# Why does nginx ignore my location block?

Tags: nginx, cache

#### Problem

I'm trying to set up different cache expiry times for different sections within my website. All pages should be cached for two days, exception for the blog-section (everything under `/blog/`), which should only stay in cache for 1 hour.

I've set up these two `location`-blocks in my nginx configuration, but no matter what I do, nginx ignores the first `location`-block when I access a `/blog/`, instead serving the default cache expiry time of 2 days.

#### Nginx configuration

```
location /blog/ {
   expires 1h;
   add_header Cache-Control "public";

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

   location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
}

location / {
   expires 2d;
   add_header Cache-Control "public";

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

   location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the first block after the second? I mean having `location /` first and then `location /blog/`

Comment: Yes, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing slash on "/blog/"? Also, read this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms and this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html